# mount.ntfs slowing computer without taking up CPU , showing “disk sleep”

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs

I have two NTFS partitions mounted in my filesystem. One of them hosts my projects, so it is very important.

Every so often, my computer gets sluggish, sometimes to the point of almost freezing up. I noticed that whenever that happens, the process `mount.ntfs` shows *`disk sleep`* in the CPU column of the System Monitor ksysguard (see screenshot below).

Notably, in those situations, the memory is *not* running out, and the CPUs are *not* running at full capacity.

What are possible explanations for this and how can I fix it?

I run Kubuntu 19.04, 64-bit.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw2u5.png)

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, "Disk sleep" is not the *cause* of the slowdown, it's just a symptom.

Right now the process isn't doing anything except waiting to receive a response to a disk read/write request. So if the disk is taking too long to respond, *any* process trying to read or write will go into the "disk sleep" or "I/O wait" state until its operation finishes.

I'm guessing the system feels slow because many of your programs are simply trying to read files from your NTFS partition, so naturally they'll be waiting for mount.ntfs to recover – and mount.ntfs itself cannot service those access requests because it is waiting for your HDD to recover.

There could be several causes:

1. There is *a lot* of disk reads or writes happening (to this physical disk as a whole; not necessarily to this specific partition). To determine if that's the cause, start with:

   - `iotop` or `iotop -Pao` to see individual programs currently performing I/O;
   - `iostat -h 1` to report the *total* I/O rate for each physical storage device.
2. The disk is busy trying to read a damaged area. (HDDs occassionally get damaged sectors – sometimes the sector can only be read after a dozen retries; sometimes it's entirely unreadable but you have to wait for the HDD to give up trying.)

   - `dmesg` or `dmesg -w` to see if the disk is reporting any read errors or other hardware problems.
3. The kernel might have bugs, e.g. disks connected through USB 3.0 in the high-performance "UAS" mode would often wedge the entire system in the past.

   - Again dmesg, but this time look for kernel reporting its own lockups *without* an associated disk read error.

If your project is important, even a *single* error reported in 'dmesg' means you should stop everything and make backups to another disk. (Actually, if your project is *actually* important, you should have been making backups already.)